# Access ONLY specific row (or fields) in CSV file with PHP - as if CSV was a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, key, row

So, I got a bit over-ambitious with what I could achieve with my limited PHP ability...  I thought it would be so simple! D:
I've achieved what I wanted to do with a PHP array, but can't replicate it using a .csv file

Originally, I created a PHP array as below:

```
$shop = array (); //replace this array later with a .csv file
$shop [0] = array ('name'=>"Bob's Butcher", 'address'=>'1 RoadStreet', 'website'=>"www.bobsbutcher.co.uk"); 
$shop [1] = array ('name'=>'Gregs Greengrocer', 'address'=>'2 Roadstreet <br/> Townville <br/> Cityland', 'website'=>'gregsgreengrocer'); 
$shop [2] = array ('name'=>'Floras Florist', 'address'=>'3 Roadstreet', 'website'=>'floraist');
```

This is a very small/simplified version of my csv file, which similarly to the example, has rows of information about shops, one row per shop

I then wrote some code which selects one of the shops from the array, by assigning this shop to the $shopNum variable.  Then, using this variable, I can pick out specific details about **that specific** shop, which can be displayed as needed on the page.

```
<div class="shopbox">
<?php $shopNum = $shop[0] ?> <!--Set the number of the shop for this section -->
<p>
<strong><?php   print $shopNum['name']; ?></strong> <br/> <!-- displays name of shop -->
<?php   print $shopNum['address']; ?> <br/>  <!-- displays shop address -->
<a target="blank" href="<?php print 'http://' . $shopNum['website']; ?>"> <?php print $shopNum['website']; ?> </a> <!-- concatenates http:// with website (incl www etc) to give auto link -->
</p>
```

The problem is, I'can't find a way to replicate this using a .csv file.  I've tried multiple methods, such as that shown below, but all I've been able to do so far is print the details for **every** shop at once, which I don't want.  What I've got below could work - it doesn't matter that the array isn't associative, as I can just replace the 'address' or 'name' keys with the relevant number.
The problem is, I can't figure out how to print for example, just the data from shop 1 - at the moment, I get shop 1, 2, 3, 4 one row after the next, but I need to be able to control which shop appears where.
Each shop has a unique ID in the first column of its row - is there any way I could use this to control which row is printed - like I did in my original script using the $shopNum variable?

```
                            $file_handle = fopen("business_detail.csv", "r");

                        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

                        $busListing = fgetcsv($file_handle, 5000);

                        print $busListing[0] . $busListing[1]. $busListing[2] . "<BR>";

                        }

                        fclose($file_handle);
```

Long story short: How would I designate a specific row in a csv array to read/print, rather than having to read/print every row.  I realise it's probably something to do with the while loop, so I've probably gone about this the wrong way, but I couldn't find another way to access the csv file that didn't use one.  Maybe the while loop needs to be replaced with the key for the row I want to use - but how would I do this?  I've seen a couple of questions asking a similar thing, but I've not had any success adapting the solutions to what I'm trying to do :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire file, but while reading it only store it in an array:

```
$fh = fopen('business_detail.csv', 'r');
while($line = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    // Stores the line (an array) into an array indexed by shop id
    $arr[$line[0]] = $line; 
}
```

Once you're done reading it, you can lookup by shop id:

```
$shopId = 'abc123';
var_dump($arr[$shopId]);
```

It is a little inefficient due to the fact that if you're only interested in a single row in the file you still have to read the *whole* file, but if it's not a very large file (*thousands* of rows) it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks watcher - that worked to get all the content of the single row displayed. (there is an error in the last line of your code though, just a ] missing! ) ;)
Also works to pull up just one field at a time, for anyone who needs to do so - just add the relevant key in [] after shopID in the last line :)

I would be using all the of the lines eventually (perhaps 30-50 lines), but they need to appear in separate places on the page - so the whole file is used in the end!  I had hit upon another solution before I saw your answer - I'll post it as an answer in a minute to see how it compares!

Comment: Apparently I'm too new to answer myself within 8 hours - so I'll have to keep everyone in suspense for another three :P  (or more, if I end up in bed!)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find another workable solution before I saw watcher's answer - posting here in case anyone is curious.  Not sure if it's the best or the technically correct way to do it (pointers welcome!) but it seems to do the job.

I started out at http://www.codedevelopr.com/articles/reading-csv-files-into-php-array/ - figuring I'd gotten this to work from an array once, if I could just get my csv data into an array, I might have more luck.

So from the above page I got:

```
<?PHP
function readCSV($csvFile){
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);
return $line_of_text;
}


// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'business_detail.csv';

$csv = readCSV($csvFile); //displays the whole csv file as an array - so you can see    what keys you need to access your data
echo '<pre>'; //comment out later
print_r($csv); //comment out later
echo '</pre>'; //comment out later
?>
```

Then added

```
<?php

print_r($csv[1][1]); //prints row 1, column 1

?>
```

Which did as it says in the comment.

Then, so that I could pull for example, the name, address, phone number, all of the same shop, without having to set which shop I wanted every time, I added

```
<p>added variable to define row (shop) at outset</p>
<?php
$rowNum = $csv[1]; //sets the current shop to csv row 1

print_r($rowNum[1]); //should print column 1 of the previously selected row (selected   by $rowNum)
```

Which also worked!  I've then commented out the echo of the whole csv, as I don't need to display that on the page, now that I know which keys/fields I need.

This seems to work, though can anyone see any issues that may arise doing it like this, in case anyone else tries to use the same solution?